# Document configuration via tags or labels?

Tags: sectioning, document-configuration

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`tagging`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tagging)

I'm trying to work out options for configuring a large [memoir](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) to multiple audiences via multiple editions.

Obviously one method of doing this is by building a master set of sections and then combining them into several different master documents which are basically a string of `\input{}` commands.

Another might be to define a set of section id environments and then include or exclude them with `\newcomment{} \commentson{} and commentsoff{}`

Yet another way would be an inverse of this: to tag each section with one or more labels. Something like this:

```
\begin{tagged}{managers,library}
\chapter{A Simple Introduction}
...
\end{tagged}
\begin{tagged}{sysprogs,library}
\chapter{A Complex Introduction}
...
\end{tagged}
\begin{tagged}{sysprogs,administrators}
\chapter{How to erase the system}
...
\end{tagged}
```

where I could then do something at the start like:

```
\usetag{sysprogs}
```

to build the "System Programmer" edition.

Is there a package that will do something like this?

---

Accepted @Leo Liu's answer. Bril.

Comment: FWIW, in ConTeXt this feature is called [modes](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modes).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a [`xcomment` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/xcomment.html), it isn't tagged, but useful for this kind of question. See also

https://texfaq.org/FAQ-conditional

---

Here is what you want:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\usetag[1]{%
  \def\do##1{\csdef{tagged@##1}{}}%
  \docsvlist{#1}}

\newenvironment{tagged}[1]%
  {\def\do##1{%
     \ifcsname tagged@##1\endcsname
       \let\comment\relax
       \let\endcomment\relax
     \fi}%
   \docsvlist{#1}
   \comment}%
  {\endcomment}

\begin{document}

\usetag{a,b,c}

\begin{tagged}{a}
aaaa
\end{tagged}

\begin{tagged}{x}
xxxx
\end{tagged}

\begin{tagged}{a, x}
aaaa xxxx
\end{tagged}

\begin{tagged}{b, c, x}
bbbb cccc xxxx
\end{tagged}

\end{document}
```

It's not difficult to implement. Whitespace after commas is ignored.

Comment: That looks brilliant, and much simpler than I had feared. Going off to have a play with it, back soon...

Comment: Accepted, +1. Brilliant. Worth an extra upvote just for the line \usepackage{etoolbox}.

Comment: A previous version does not contain `etoolbox`. I used `\@for` and `\@namedef`, which is not more complex. I use `etoolbox` to ignore the extra spaces. However, unlike `keyval`, spaces before commas is not ignored. You can use `\ForEach` in `forarray` package or other trick to ignore more spaces.

Answer (score 9):

The [`tagging' package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tagging) is now on CTAN, providing the following commands:

```
\tagged{list}{yes}            % Conditional inclusion
\untagged{list}{no}           % Conditional exclusion
\iftagged{list}{yes}{no}      % Conditional inclusion/exclusion
\begin{taggedblock}{list}     % Conditionally included environment
    \end{taggedblock}         %
\begin{untaggedblock}{list}   % Conditionally excluded environment
    \end{taggedblock}         %
\usetag{list}                 % Turn tags on
\droptag{list}                % Turn tags off
```

My thanks to [Leo Liu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2674/leo-liu), for his original answer on which the work is based.

Comment: Good job. I've just seen this package on CTAN-ann mailing list.

Comment: I was very happy when I found `tagging`.  Does this package have the ability to list the tags in use? Somewhat along the lines of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37928/is-there-an-easy-way-to-tag-content-in-a-latex-document

Comment: @AFeldman I'm sorry, I have good news: I'm in the process of freezing and deprecating `tagging`, in favour of Boris Veytsman's `multiaudience`, which I think does a better job. `tagging` will remain on CTAN, in order not to force current users to migrate, but there will no further development, and no bug or feature requests will be accepted.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough much obliged for the response.  I will take a look at `multiaudience`.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough the `tagging` documentation is very understandable.  I found myself wishing that the same was true with `multiaudience`, which I found a little confusing.  Is there a technical reason why `multiaudience` is better?

Comment: @AFeldman I'm very much an amateur tinkerer; Boris has much more experience than I do. I believe `multiaudience` handles many more edge cases than does `tagging`. I'm sorry, but thank you for your kind words on the dox.