# How to add an option to include or exclude some newcommands

Tags: pdftex

I defined several new commands like this:

```
\newcommand{\NAME1}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.41,0.66,0.88}{(NAME1): #1}}
\newcommand{\NAME2}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.8,0.2,0.3}{(NAME2): #1}}
```

I used them to add comments and I would like to know how can I add something in my preamble maybe to choose whether I want those commands to be included or not in the final pdf?

Thanks

Comment: First of all, "commands" are not included in the pdf, it depends on how you use it. Secondly, you cannot put digits in command names.

Comment: Of course commands will not be included, I meant the TEXT that is generated with those commands. The numbers are just an EXAMPLE. There are DIFFERENT NAMES...I thought those 2 things were PRETTY obvious to clarify them....

Comment: Well, more explanation could be helpful. Of course you can declare a boolean variable like [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58624/variables-for-hiding-or-showing-text-in-latex) and use a macro to toggle between true/false code. However, since there is only one line of code, you can also write two versions in the preamble and comment the one you don't want...

Comment: I was thinking if there would be an option to "exinclude" a list of commands in one line on the preamble for example rather than using two versions....because like that I could just simply comment out in each line they are written which is what I am doing now but it is troublesome

Comment: @airpod Again, the example link may be helpful. You can set a boolean variable with `\newif` and form your definition like so:`\iflong <def1> \else <def2> \fi `. Now you can switch between `<def1>` and `<def2>` by using one command.