# Compiling one tex file with two styles

Tags: document-classes, books, sv-classes, styles

I am working on a book project with Springer. I finished a draft with their style file and it complies well.

Now, I hope to put this on ArXiv after stripping out all the proprietary material including springer logo and their style files. I already made a amsbook version also, by changing (for example)

Springer: `\abstract{foo bar}`
amsbook: `\begin{abstract}foo bar\end{abstract}`

There are several other points as well. (`\spnewtheorem` vs `\newtheorem` etc) It took me quite some effort.

In such a case, is it possible to maintain a single TeX file, or at least two files with minimal changes, so that simultaneous editing is not so hard? It sounds painful to edit the two files synchronously whenever I find typos in the future.

One brute force way would be I make lots of source files
abstract-chapter1.tex
abstract-chapter2.tex
etc..

and make

springer.tex
`\abstract{\include{abstract-chapter1}}`

amsbook-source.tex
`\begin{abstract}\include{abstract-chapter1}\end{abstract}`

and so forth. But this method still seems to require too much unnecessary work. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You surely shouldn't use `\include` for the abstract, but rather `\input`.

Comment: Please consider https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58624/3850 as an answer to your question. It offers several ways to accomplish what you want. If your TeX-Foo is lacking and get back to me, I can provide a full answer with explanation(s).