# Indenting text from '\enumerate'

Tags: indentation, input, import

I am trying to write a document that has the same question in two places. So, I've written that question down in a seperate tex file, and used the `\input` command in both places to copy the question.

However, the question has parts (a, b, c) and I would like each part to have its own, seperate tex file. Once I have done so, I used the \input command twice, once for the original quetsion, and the second for the respective part.

Here is the minimal main.tex file used in this project:

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{book}
%____________________________Packages____________________________________
\usepackage{import} % For large project management
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} % For enumeration and lists
\usepackage[margin=1 in]{geometry} % Adds 1 inch margins 

%___________________________Page Style_______________________________________________
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} % Removes all indentation
\newcommand{\tab}{\hspace*{1cm}}
% __________________________________Body__________________________________
\begin{document}    

\include{Problem_1a}

\end{document}
```

Here is what Question_1.tex file contains:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item[1.]
  Some question \#1.
\end{enumerate}
```

Here is what Question_1a.tex file contains:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item[a.]
    Some part 1a.
\end{enumerate}
```

And, finally, here is the code in question, contained in Problem_1a.tex:

```
\import{./}{Question_1}
% \tab\import{./}{Question_1a}
\tab{}\input{Question_1a}

\textit{Solution.}
\newline
```

which generates:

[image]

However, the `\input` command (also the `\import` command) seems to create a new line automatically, and even if I put a `\tab` command (that I've written as a macro) it will skip that line and create another.

This is how I want the final result to look like.

[image]

But that was only accomplished manually by:

```
\begin{enumerate}[1.]
    \item 
    Some question \#1.
    \begin{enumerate}[a.]
        \item 
        Some part 1a.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

How do I force the input command to indent the text it contains (also without creating additional space)?

Note: I don't want to use `\input{Question_1a}` within Question_1.tex because I want to use Quesiton_1.tex seperatley elsewhere within the document.

Comment: In my experience, `\import` or `\input` introduce only a space afterwards, not a new line. Are there blank lines at the start or end of the file you're inputting/import? Can you post a complete [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), including the definition of `\tab`, along with a sample inputted file for it that generates this problem? In general, you should always post code, never screenshots of code.

Comment: Isn't the obvious solution here is to (correctly) do the `\input` of 1a inside Question_1.tex.instead?

Comment: (like how you would type it by hand manually. What's the issue?)

Comment: This is not a *minimal* working example, as it is nowhere near minimal.  Please *read* the page I linked in my previous message. But I'm pretty sure your problem has *nothing* to do with `\input` or `\import`. You'd get the same result if you copied and pasted the results. The enumerate environment starts a new paragraph. You can't indent it that way.

Comment: Is it that you don't want to put the `\input` for Question_1a.tex inside Question_1.tex (As user202729 suggests) because you sometimes want to use Question_1.tex without including the solution? Rather than trying to emulate an enumerate inside an enumerate with a tab, you could put the `\input` for Question_1a.tex in Question_1.tex but inside a boolean conditional.See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58624/variables-for-hiding-or-showing-text-in-latex). There are also classes specializing in problems and solutions with builtin mechanisms for this like xsim and exercise.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestions, this the first time I've posted on Stack Exchange. Yes, I don't want to put the \input for Question_1a.tex inside Question_1.tex, because I want to use Question_1.tex seperately at times. I'll check out the link rn, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Is there an environment that simply tabulates everything contained within it (like enumerate does, but without the letter or number up at front)? Because then enumerate problem is solved easily.

I looked at the boolean conditional, but the thing is, I have many parts to the question, and mutiple questions as well. After understanding it, I'll have to implement it for each and every one of them (I could write a program that automatically creates the files and contents because it gets repetitive) but still its a lot.

The specialized classes may help, so I'll look into that in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to force the text from the `\input` command to be indented, I was able to use the enumerate environment within Question_1a.tex to make it appear as if it was indented. The Question_1a.tex was modified to be:

```
\begin{enumerate}[\empty]
    \item 
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item[a.]
        Some part 1a.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

This produced the output:

[image]

as desired.

I'm guessing there is a better enviroment that is more suited to create this indentation, so if anyone knows of it, let me know in the comments.